# Why minikube runs as a container itself?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube, orchestra

While playing around with Docker and orchestration (kubernetes) I had to install and use minikube to create a simple sandbox environment. At the beginning I thought that minikube installs some kind of VM and run the "minified" kubernetes environment inside the same, however, after the installation listing my local Docker running containers I found minikube running as a container!!

Why minikube itself run as a Docker container? and how can it runs other containers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Experimental Docker support looks to have been [added](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#version-170-beta0---2020-01-15) in minikube 1.7.0, and [started becoming the default runtime](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#version-190-beta1---2020-03-18) in minikube 1.9.0.  As I'm writing this, current is 1.15.1.

The [minikube documentation on the "docker" driver](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/docker/) notes, particularly on a native-Linux host, there is not an intermediate virtual machine: if you can run Kubernetes in a container, it can use the entire host system's resources without special configuration or partitioning.  The previous minikube-on-VirtualBox installation required preallocating memory and disk to the VM, and it was easy to get those settings wrong.  Even on non-Linux hosts, if you're running Docker Desktop, sharing its hidden Linux VM can improve resource utilization, and you don't need to decide to allocate exactly 2 GB RAM to Docker Desktop and exactly 4 GB to the minikube VM.

For a long time it's been possible, but discouraged, to run a separate Docker daemon inside a Docker container; similarly, it's possible, but usually discouraged, to run a multi-process init system in a container.  If you do both of these things then you can have the core Kubernetes components (etcd, apiserver, kubelet, ...) inside a single container pretending to be a Kubernetes node.  It also helps here that Kubernetes already knows how to pull Docker images, which minimizes some of the confusing issues with running Docker in Docker.